# Error running Cordova/Phonegap 1.7 app on Android 4.0/4.0.3

Tags: android, cordova

Does a Cordova 1.7 (Phonegap) mobile app have problems running on Android 4.0 and 4.0.3 when page transitions have query string parameters? The app works fine in Android 2.3.3 and 4.1 but not on 4.0 or 4.0.3. I get the dreaded "Unknown chromium error: -6" error on the transition.

Comment: can you paste some of your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap doesn't have the problem. Google has the problem. Please go star:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

In the meantime you should try PhoneGap 2.0.0 as Joe put in a work around for this issue. If that doesn't work or if you can't upgrade use localStorage to pass parameters between pages.